# Can I set a standard path to Qt-directory in a .pro file?

Tags: qt, qmake

is there a way to define the path to the qt directory in a `.pro` file? 
I've tried `INCLUDEPATH +=` and `LIB +=` but after qmake in the makefile always stands /usr/share/qt4 and /usr/include/qt4/ for the path to the directory where qt is installed... Maybe I could say I want to replace `/usr/` with `/home/ubuntu/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/gcc` or some other stuff.

Comment: It's pretty unusual to set the path to Qt in a project file. More than likely you probably just want to ensure $QTDIR is set correctly and that you're running the qmake that is located here: `/home/ubuntu/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/gcc/bin/qmake ...` (the qmake you're running that is adding the `/usr` paths is probably the qmake that came installed on the system).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @Linville  says is right.  Use the correct qmake and those paths will be what you want.

Generally you should not need to set QTDIR and just running the correct qmake should work.

eg

```
export PATH=/home/ubuntu/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/gcc/bin:$PATH
mkdir -p $HOME/build/myapp && cd $HOME/build/myapp
# check you have the right qmake
which qmake && qmake -query
# shadow build so as to not pollute your source tree
qmake $HOME/source/myapp/myapp.pro
```

If for some reason you want to refer to the paths listed by qmake -query you can use $$[QT_INSTALL_DATA] for example.

Comment: Side note: if you're having issues grabbing/running tools/libs from the qt directory during qmake, reboot. I had an issue where windeployqt was never working, forcing me to link directly to the qt directory. After removing the direct path and rebooting, windeployqt started to work. Something something, IT Crowd.

Answer (score 0):

I have issue with header file not found, so I used `export path` before `qmake` which solved my problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33447617)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).